# Reflect.Value.FieldByName causing Panic

Tags: reflection, go

I'm getting the following error when calling the .FieldByName method of a reflected value, the exact error is :-

```
panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.FieldByName on ptr Value
```

and the code is :-

```
s := reflect.ValueOf(&value).Elem() (value is a struct)
metric := s.FieldByName(subval.Metric).Interface() (subval.Metric is a string)
```

I understand this isn't much, but this is all the information I can get.

Here's a link to the code on Go Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/E038cPOoGp

Comment: the error message is pretty clear. Can you make a runnable example in the playground? (and `value` may be a struct, `&value` is a pointer)

Comment: Updated the main post with a link to the code in the playground (http://play.golang.org/p/E038cPOoGp)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your `value` is already a pointer to a struct. Try printing out `s.Kind()` in your code.

There's no reason to take the address of `value`, then call `Elem()` on that `reflect.Value`, which dereferences the pointer you just created.

```
s := reflect.ValueOf(value).Elem()
metric := s.FieldByName(subvalMetric).Interface()
fmt.Println(metric)
```

Comment: I'd personally replace `s := reflect.ValueOf(value).Elem()` with `s := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(value))`, that way the same code will work on both structs and pointers to structs. [reflect.Indirect](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Indirect)

Answer (score 4):

If you add few println you understand what happens:

http://play.golang.org/p/-kaz105_En

```
for _, Value:= range NewMap {
    s := reflect.ValueOf(&Value).Elem()
    println(s.String())
    println(s.Elem().String())
    metric := s.Elem().FieldByName(subvalMetric).Interface()
    fmt.Println(metric)
}
```

Output:

```
<*main.Struct1 Value>
<main.Struct1 Value>
abc
```