# Display Foreign Keys of Foreign Keys in Go GORM

Tags: sqlite, go, gorilla, go-gorm

I was able to partially solve this with [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435783/gorm-golang-orm-associations)

Unfortunately, the Preload() function doesn't seem to work with delving further down in the related object set.

To clarify, I have the following models:

```
    type Room struct {
        gorm.Model
        Name    string
        Games   []Game `gorm:"ForeignKey:RoomID"`
    }

    type Game struct {
        gorm.Model
        RoomID   int `gorm:"index"`
        Players  []Player `gorm:"ForeignKey:GameID"`
    }

    type Player struct {
        gorm.Model
        Name   string
        GameID int `gorm:"index"`
    }
```

When I create a new object with a new Room, Game, and Player object created I get the following data returned (json encoded):

```
    {"Value":{"ID":26,"CreatedAt":"2016-05-15T01:21:22.426234189-07:00","UpdatedAt":"2016-05-15T01:21:22.426234189-07:00","DeletedAt":null,"Name":"foo","Games":[{"ID":17,"CreatedAt":"2016-05-15T01:21:22.427026134-07:00","UpdatedAt":"2016-05-15T01:21:22.427026134-07:00","DeletedAt":null,"RoomID":26,"Turns":null,"Players":[{"ID":4,"CreatedAt":"2016-05-15T01:21:22.427560561-07:00","UpdatedAt":"2016-05-15T01:21:22.427560561-07:00","DeletedAt":null,"Name":"TestPlayer","GameID":17}],"Counter":1,"Assigned":false}],"Testing":false},"Error":null,"RowsAffected":1}
```

But if I try to query the structure with a preload() function, I get the following:

```
    {"Value":{"ID":26,"CreatedAt":"2016-05-15T01:21:22.426234189-07:00","UpdatedAt":"2016-05-15T01:21:22.426234189-07:00","DeletedAt":null,"Name":"foo","Games":[{"ID":17,"CreatedAt":"2016-05-15T01:21:22.427026134-07:00","UpdatedAt":"2016-05-15T01:21:22.427026134-07:00","DeletedAt":null,"RoomID":26,"Turns":null,"Players":null,"Counter":1,"Assigned":false}],"Testing":false},"Error":null,"RowsAffected":1}
```

Note that the Players section is now null. Here's my room registration and room query functions:

```
    func RegisterRoom(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        err := r.ParseForm()

        if err != nil {
            // Handle error
        }
        // r.PostForm is a map of our POST form values
        room := Room{
            Name: r.PostFormValue("label"),
            Games: []Game{{
                Counter: 1,
                Players: []Player{{Name: r.PostFormValue("username")}},
            }},
        }
        t := db.Create(&room)
        if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(t); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

func RoomShow(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var rm Room
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    roomId := vars["roomId"]
    id, _ := strconv.Atoi(roomId)
    room := db.Preload("Games").First(&rm, id)
    result := db.Find(&room)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(result)
}
```

Comment: Solved it! Answer was under [Nested Preloading](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/curd.html#preloading-eager-loading)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! Answer was under [Nested Preloading](http://jinzhu.me/gorm/curd.html#preloading-eager-loading) *smacks forehead*