# How to declare foreign key relationship in go-xorm for postgres?

Tags: go, go-xorm

I want to declare foreign key relation between tables using XORM in golang for postgres.

I've tried the following schema to create foreign key relationship.

```
type Author struct {
    Id uint64 `xorm:"pk autoincr"`
    Name string `xorm:"VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL"`
    Email string `xorm:"VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL UNIQUE"`
    Phone string `xorm:"VARCHAR(32)"`
    Age float32
    Address string `xorm:"VARCHAR(256)"`

    Created time.Time `xorm:"created"`
    Updated time.Time `xorm:"updated"`
}


type Book struct {
    Id uint64 `xorm:"pk autoincr"`
    Name string `xorm:"varchar(128) NOT NULL"`
    Isbn string `xorm:"varchar(64) NOT NULL"`
    Author *Author `xorm:"-"`

    Created time.Time `xorm:"created"`
    Updated time.Time `xorm:"updated"`
}
```

And then,

```
err := engine.Sync(new(models.Author))
err = engine.Sync(new(models.Book))
```

But the above code doesn't create foreign key, even no column named author in Book table.
Help me to solve this problem that how i can declare foreign key for postgres.

Comment: It seems to not exist: https://github.com/go-xorm/xorm/issues/73

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435783/gorm-golang-orm-associations

Comment: @RickyA their github page has been moved to another platform, but here's an issue reply from a month ago where they explicitly say they dont support foreign keys right now https://gitea.com/xorm/xorm/issues/1627